# How to getElementById using DOM?

Tags: java, android, dom, getelementbyid

I am having part of HTML page given below and want to extract the content of div tag its id is `hiddenDivHL` using DOM Parser:

#### Part Of a HTML Page:

```
<div id='hiddenDivHL' style='display:none'>http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details.php?home=0&catid=882&newsid=123069[InnerSep]http://www.udayavani.com/udayavani_cms/gall_content/2012/1/2012_1$thumbimg117_Jan_2012_000221787.jpg[InnerSep]ಯುವಜನತೆಯಿಂದ ಭವ್ಯಭಾರತ[OuterSep]
```

So far I have used the below code but I am unable to use `getElementById`.How to do that?

#### DOM Parser:

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details_android.php?home=1&catid=882&newsid=27593");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
        name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            name[i] = new TextView(this);
            
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("hiddenDivHL");
            Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
            nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
            name[i].setText("Name = "
                    + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            
            layout.addView(name[i]);
            
            

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);

}
```

Comment: `doc.getElementById("hiddenDivHL")` If that doesn't work then use a real DOM.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById(java.lang.String)

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Illegal: "<" inside attribute value (position:START_TAG <link rel='stylesheet' href='no-cache'>@12:64 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40573f30)

Answer (score 2):

XPath is IMHO the most common and easiest way to navigate the DOM in Java.

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details_android.php?home=1&   catid=882&newsid=27593");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/item/div[@id='hiddenDivHL']";
    Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);  

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
```

I'm not sure if the XPath expression is right, but the link is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 differences between getElementById and getElementsByName:

1. getElementById requires a single unique id in your document, whereas getElementsByName can fetch several occurances of the same name.
2. getElementById is a method (or function) of the document object.  You can only access it by using document.getElementById(..).

Your code seems to violate both these requirements, you seem to go through a loop of nodes and expect a hiddenDivHL id in each node list. So the id is not unique. Second your root point is not the document but the root point of each node in that list.

If you know you have a single instance with that id try document.getElementById.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get the question.

a) Do you mean getting more elements by document.getElementById('hiddenDivHL')?

- so my answer would be that, in a HTML-Document, the id has to be reserved for one element only.

b) If you just want to catch that element?

- what exactly does not work? what are you trying to achieve? I fear I don't really get the point.

Comment: @nabittened-I want to get the contents of 'hiddenDivHL' element.

Comment: should workd with `document.getElementById('hiddenDivHL')` for the element resp. `document.getElementById('hiddenDivHL').innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("div");` to get all div's elements and them check if their attribute id is equal `hiddenDivHL`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i can think of is to use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library, what it does is parse the DOM for you and lets you select elements using a css style (or jquery style) selector.

in this example you would do something like this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://74.127.61.106/udayavaniIpad/details_android.php?home=1&catid=882&newsid=27593").get();
String divContents = doc.select("#hiddenDivHL").first().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unable to use getElementById()? It is in [JavaSE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29) and JavaSE6/5/1.4.2, since 'DOM Level 2'.

Answer (score -5):

To get the contents of an element in JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hiddenDivHL');
var contents = el.innerHTML;
alert("Found " + contents.length + " characters of content.");
```

See [your example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zymsys/JzVFe/).

I think the confusion is due to the fact that your question is tagged JavaScript, but the code you posted is Java.  They are different languages, and JavaScript people will only be confused by that parser.  I haven't used Java in years so I can't really help you there.

Comment: The DOM API exists in Java as well. You can load a HTML file into a Java DOM.